# Fetch contents of confluence article through REST api with only the tiny URL

Tags: rest, jira, confluence, confluence-rest-api

Is there a way to use the Confluence REST api to fetch the content of an article if all I have is the tiny url?  I know how to do it if I have the page ID or the space/title, but so far I can't figure out a way to translate these tiny urls into something usable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @mtheriault said, a workaround is necessary, you can't directly push the tiny url into the REST API. However, there's an easier way than reading the html source:

You need one normal REST call but instead of querying the tinyurl itself, GET the following: `[confluenceURL]/pages/tinyurl.action?urlIdentifier=[tinyURLFragment]`. If the tiny url fragment is correct, you will get a 302 where the `Location` header is the fully qualified link to that page. Then you can parse the space key, page title and whatever else you need from it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some code, but it's possible.

The tiny URL is only a redirect (302) to the page in Confluence.

The process should be something like this:

- Make a GET request on the Tiny URL. Follow the redirect (302).
- You will get the page content. If you inspect a Confluence page, you will see that some meta are available:

  `<meta name="ajs-page-id" content="6494177">
  <meta name="ajs-latest-page-id" content="6494177">
  <meta name="ajs-content-type" content="page">
  <meta name="ajs-page-title" content="Page Title">
  <meta name="ajs-latest-published-page-title" content="Page Title">
  <meta name="ajs-parent-page-title" content="My Parent Page Title">
  <meta name="ajs-parent-page-id" content="6496957">
  <meta name="ajs-space-key" content="CT">
  <meta name="ajs-space-name" content="My Space">`
- Parse and get the required values to fetch the content of the page: https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest/#content-getContent.

Comment: I appreciate the response and the workaround but I was hoping for a way to do it through the REST API.